# List static ressources in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a Spring project that serves a rather large number of audio files from the static resource folder (`src/main/resources/static/sound/`). I've got that working just fine – the files are accessible over HTTP. However, I'd also like to send a directory listing to the client so it knows which files are available, preferably as JSON. Typing that list by hand would be tedious, especially since new files are likely to be added in the future. Google results only tell me how to serve the files in the first place, but I've got that already.

tl;dr: Is there a way to list all static resources in a Spring project?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to list all sounds files:

```
Set<String> sounds = Stream.of(new File(dir).listFiles())
      .filter(file -> !file.isDirectory())
      .map(File::getName)
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

and in one of your controller, return sounds object:

```
    @GetMapping("/GetAllSounds")
    String home() {
        Set<String> sounds = Stream.of(new File(dir).listFiles())
      .filter(file -> !file.isDirectory())
      .map(File::getName)
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return sounds 
    }
```

for best practice, you should encapsulation sounds to a service class

Comment: Thanks, but this reads the directory directly from the disk, right? Won't this break when I deploy the application as a single jar file?

Comment: then i think you should move these sounds to some other directory out of the jar file.

Comment: So in other words, what I'm trying to do is not possible? What a bummer. Thank you anyway!